# Magento pages broken after editing product view.phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I was writing some custom php for the product view page in Magento, and accidentally executed an infinite while loop on the server. I erased this code (I've gone all the way to put view.phtml back to what it was before I started working with it), flushed/cleared every kind of cache, even deleted cache manually but NO pages are working on the site. They all hang forever, which makes it seem as though they're all executing the infinite while loop (even non-product pages.) I have no idea what to do at this point to fix this - any ideas?

Comment: maybe the are still running and block every new call. if you are using apache2 try restarting it. if you are using nginx + php-fpm restart php-fpm

Comment: You're right - now I"m getting a Resource Limit reached error. Shared hosting unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are maybe still running.

If you are using apache2 restart it, if your are using nginx restart php-fpm.

However, if cant restart or kill processes and you did not exec them over the console, you should reach the max_execution time of you server. by default this is 60 seconds so this problem should solve itself in time.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear All folder mannualy inside var/cache and var/session dir.

Also Please check with diffrent browsers. May be this helps you